# Setting up central system to run selenium scripts

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am working on automation project. I have completed all test cases and executing in my local. Now my Project Manager wants to be execute it in a server so any one can access and execute the scripts. Is there any possible to place in a server. Please let me know If any chances ASAP

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the solution is to setup Continues Integration server like Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity or something else.

You may need also a Selenium Hub/Grid to scale better both for the number of tests and browsers.